# ffmpeg: preserve quality in trimmed video from a HEVC (h.265) source video

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, obs, h.265

I've have some screen recorded video with OBS software using the video codec "NVIDIA NVENC HEVC" (which is h.265 via GPU hardware) using CQP level 17.

Full encoder options in OBS were:
[image]

The output is a 06:08:33.94 long video, (around 5.6GB) that I need to slice into shorter videos trimmed at specific timestamps. Because of how h.264 and h.265 works, it seems I need to re-encode whole the video to do that without missing the first few seconds of each trimmed video. The full output of `ffprobe` this source file is:

```
ffprobe.exe source-00.mp4
ffprobe version 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\source-00.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 06:08:33.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2179 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-1), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1976 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 190 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

The thing is I'm happy with the current quality, I'd like that this re-encoding process does mess as less as possible with the original quality, while maintaining the sum of all the output videos not to far away in size to those 5.6GB from the original source.

The first thing I tried, was to trim some unwanted footage from the beginning and the end of the source, and following this suggestion from [this answer superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1056632/535840), I didn't specify any options to the video codec:

> ffmpeg will automatically attempt to use many of the same parameters
> when encoding including: frame rate, width, height, pixel format,
> audio channel layout, audio sample rate, etc. So you usually don't
> have to do anything special.

So:
ffmpeg -i source-00.mp4 -ss 00:00:01.80 -to 06:07:34.0 -map 0 -c copy -c:v libx265 actual-footage-0.mp4

After many hours of re-encoding the result was a 1.26GB video with a much worse quality, full info:

```
ffprobe actual-footage-0.mp4
ffprobe version 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'actual-footage-0.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Duration: 06:07:32.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 493 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, bt709/bt709/iec61966-2-1, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 289 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx265
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

**What can I do to preserve the quality as much a possible while re-encoding a HEVC video?**

Comment: Try either of the tools from this answer - https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30269/edit-small-portion-of-a-compressed-video-without-losing-quality/30272#30272. I've only used them for H.264, but I know Smart Renderer at least is supposed to do H.265 also.